# Mulesoft create new Mule Project from local raml shows disabled finish button

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, raml

I am creating a new Mule project within Anypoint Studio and the finish button is disabled. I followed the steps here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.15/import-api-specification-local-file and everything appears to be in order except I can't click finish. Is this a Anypoint Studio defect or am I missing something?

[image]

Here is my raml

```
 #%RAML 1.0 
title: placeholder
version: v1
baseUri: http://myapi.com/v1/api
/postPlanDtls:
  Post:
    description: Sends plan details 
    body:
        application/json:
            example: |
                {
                "id":1,
                "url":"http://google.com"
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your API that Studio is not reporting. Replace the method `Post:` by `post:` and try again. There is a bug in that it doesn't show the right error, but the problem is in your RAML.